# Как в T-SQL обратится к таблице по вычисляемому имени

Tags: sql-server

Требуется обратится к таблице, имя которой заранее не известно, но может быть вычислено. Например

```
Select * from 'table_' + @tableName
```

Это вообще возможно? а то таблицы генерируются на лету из кода, а мне нужен скрипт на T-SQL.

Comment: Динамическим SQL - скажем, в рамках хранимой процедуры.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться процедурой `sp_executesql`. Например так:

```
DECLARE @selectString NVARCHAR(700) = N'SELECT * FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@tableName)
EXEC sp_executesql @selectString
```